# Adopting Unifi devices on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

I have put a unifi controller online in digitalocean k8s which works. Unfortunately I can't adopt any devices to it. When I SSH into the device and set the inform to the controller on `http://unifi."domain".net:8080/inform`
it doesn't show up. I have also tried some different combinations for the URL. Here are my configs. I hope some of you have some suggestions.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: unifi-service
  namespace: unifi-ns
spec:
  selector:
    app: unifi
  ports:
    - port: 443 # Default port for image
      targetPort: 8443
      name: https
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 8080
      name: inform
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 6789
      name: ubnt-6789
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 8443
      name: ubnt-8443
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 3478
      name: ubnt-3478
      protocol: UDP
    - port: 8881
      name: ubnt-8881
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 8882
      name: ubnt-8882
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 10001
      name: ubnt-10001
      protocol: UDP
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: unifi-ingress
  namespace: unifi-ns
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - unifi."domain".net
    secretName: unifi-tls
  rules:
  - host: unifi."domain".net
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: unifi-service
            port:
              number: 443
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: unifi-set
  namespace: unifi-ns
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: unifi
  serviceName: "unifi-service"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: unifi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: unifi
        image: jacobalberty/unifi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: unifi-pvc
          mountPath: /unifi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6789
          name: ubnt-6789
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: ubnt-8080
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: ubnt-8443
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 3478
          name: ubnt-3478
          protocol: UDP
        - containerPort: 8881
          name: ubnt-8881
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8882
          name: ubnt-8882
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 10001
          name: ubnt-10001
          protocol: UDP      
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: unifi-pvc
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
      storageClassName: do-block-storage
```

Comment: Does your cluster have a running ingress controller? Also, you say that you're setting the URL to use port 8080 - is the ingress controller exposed on that port? If so, is it public on your IP? Does the underlying service understand '/inform' or are you trying to route traffic to the service that way? Why are you using an ingress controller if you're not using layer-7 routing (i.e. an ingress controller is usually used with a meaningful path, otherwise you could just use the LoadBalancer service type for layer 4 routing)?

Comment: Yes it has a ingress controller. It is there to split the traffic between different instances. The ip is hosted in the cloud via digital ocean. The standard unifi route is /inform i tried adding a inform route to the ingress but that didnt change the behaviour.